# jquery data export without showing data in the datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, export

This is my table code -

```
                                                <table id="table-data" class="table border table-striped table-bordered text-nowrap dataTable" style="width: 100%;" role="grid" >
                                              <thead>
                                                <tr role="row">
                                                  <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="default_order" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 129px;">Dates</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 193px;">Time</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 129px;">Cluster Name</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 193px;">Region Name</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 92px;">Area Name</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">Distribution H. Name</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">Designation</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">Robi MSISDN</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">Airtel MSISDN</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">Name</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">Date Of Birth</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">Joining Date</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">Contact Number</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">NID/Birth Cer.</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">NID/Birth Cer. Number</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">Education Qualification</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">Personal MFS A/C</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 31px;">Personal MFS A/C No.</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 66px;">Marital Status</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 66px;">Spouse Name</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 66px;">Spouse DOB</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 66px;">Child1 Name</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 66px;">Child1 DOB</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 66px;">Child2 Name</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 66px;">Child2 DOB</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 66px;">Self Image</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 66px;">NID Image</th>
                                                  <th class="sorting_desc" tabindex="1" aria-controls="default_orderx" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="descending" style="width: 66px;">Status</th>
                                                
                                    
                                    
                                                </tr>
                                              </thead>
                                              <tbody>
                                                 <?php if($dsrInfoLoadAllData !=NULL) : ?>
                                                    <?php foreach($dsrInfoLoadAllData as $index => $row) : ?>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['date']) ? $row['date'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['time']) ? $row['time'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['cluster_name']) ? $row['cluster_name'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['region_name']) ? $row['region_name'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['area_name']) ? $row['area_name'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['distribution_house_name']) ? $row['distribution_house_name'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['designation_type']) ? $row['designation_type'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['el_number_robi']) ? $row['el_number_robi'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['el_number_airtl']) ? $row['el_number_airtl'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['individual_name']) ? $row['individual_name'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['individual_dob']) ? $row['individual_dob'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['joining_date']) ? $row['joining_date'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['individual_contact']) ? $row['individual_contact'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['pers_identity_options']) ? $row['pers_identity_options'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <?php if(isset($row['nid_number'])){
                                                                $hello = $row['nid_number'];
                                                            }
                                                            elseif(isset($row['birth_cer_no'])){
                                                                $hello = $row['birth_cer_no'];
                                                            }
                                                            else $hello = '';
                                                            $hello = $row['nid_number'].$row['birth_cer_no'];
                                                        ?>
                                                        <td><?php echo $hello; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['edu_degree_type']) ? $row['edu_degree_type'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['transac_brand_type']) ? $row['transac_brand_type'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['transac_brand_number']) ? $row['transac_brand_number'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['marital_status']) ? $row['marital_status'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['spouse_name']) ? $row['spouse_name'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                         <td><?php echo isset($row['spouse_dob']) ? $row['spouse_dob'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['child1_name']) ? $row['child1_name'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['child1_dob']) ? $row['child1_dob'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['child2_name']) ? $row['child2_name'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['child2_dob']) ? $row['child2_dob'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['self_image']) ? "https://dogotal.com/Robi-Retailer/userpanel/".$row['self_image'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['nid_image']) ? "https://dogotal.com/Robi-Retailer/userpanel/".$row['nid_image'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                        <td><?php echo isset($row['status']) ? $row['status'] : ''; ?></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                                
                                               
                                              </tbody>
                                            </table>
```

This is my export button code(CSV, excel is almost same) -

```
        $('#btn--export_pdf').on('click', function(){
            // Destroy the existing DataTable instance
            dataTable.destroy();
            dataTable = $('#table-data').DataTable( {
                    suppressWarnings: true,
                    lengthMenu: [ 10, 25, 50, 100 ], // Provide a dropdown menu to select page length
                    pageLength: 10, // Default to 25 records per pag
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        
                        {
                            extend: 'pdf',
                            text: 'Download PDF',
                            filename: 'table-data',
                            orientation: 'landscape',
                            pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: ':visible'
                            },
                            customize: function(doc) {
                              // Exclude columns with the class 'exclude'
                              doc.content[1].table.body.forEach(function(row) {
                                row.splice(-1, 1); // Remove the second column (index 1)
                                // row.splice(-2, 2); // Remove the third column (index 2)
                                row.splice(-3, 2); // Remove the third column (index 3)
                              });
                              doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 6;
                              doc.content[1].table.headerRows = 1;
                              doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 6;
                              doc.styles.tableHeader.bold = false;
                            }
                            
                  
                        }
                    ],
                    responsive: true,
            });
        });
```

I don't want to show the data in the table, but export the pdf, excel, and CSV with valid data. But if I use the CSS - display: none; or something technique, data is not exported, and the pdf is blank.

Can anyone come up with any idea?

Comment: did you try css visibility property?

Comment: i tried with display:none . but the downloaded pdf was empty

Comment: i understand. display none remove the element from dom, try visibility